# Is it necessary for an employer to claim employee rental housing as a paid benefit?

Tags: income-tax, canada, benefits

A friend of mine pays to rent housing from her employer.  This housing is owned and managed by the employer and rented only to employees.  They agreed upon a rent of $X per month when she moved in and after about 6 months, the employer is now claiming that the rent is significantly below market value and her pay stubs now list an additional $400 per month in employer paid benefits in the form of a housing subsidy.  The employer claims that the market value of the rental unit has increased due to "increased nearby amenities".

Needless to say, my friend is extremely unhappy about this because the tax implications will result in her housing costs increasing by over $100 per month.  The employer insists that their hands are tied on this matter and it's purely tax law at work and they don't have a choice but to declare this added paid benefit.

I'm not an accountant but my view on this is as follows:  Anyone can rent a housing unit for any price, as long as its agreeable to both the tenant and landlord and all tenancy laws are followed.  So with that in mind, it would appear that the employer is simply looking to write-off this supposed discrepancy between the current rent and the 'market value' to pay fewer taxes and those tax savings are coming at the expense of the tenants.  It seems like an underhanded way to indirectly squeeze more rent from the tenants.  It really does seem like a cash grab, as they are also claiming her parking spot at the residence is priced below market value and that is listed as a paid benefit too.

Is this view correct?  If the employer wanted to do right by their employees, could they choose NOT to declare this supposed housing subsidy as a paid benefit?  Or are their hands truly tied here by some tax law?

Comment: How do you figure that the employer declaring a higher value for the taxable benefit means more money in their pocket? I don't follow that part.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea If they're using this "expense" as a deduction, they will pay fewer taxes as a result.  And some portion of those tax obligations will be shifted to the employee tenants.  In other words, the government gets their money either way but the employer has used a subjective number (the market value) to get creative with their accounting and shift some of their tax burden to the employees.  The net result is less money in the employees' pockets and more in the employer's.

Comment: @stackunderflow this is incorrect. This is not an expense and they do not deduct it. In fact - they'll pay more taxes, since payroll taxes will apply to this benefit as well.

Comment: @littleadv Can you explain this?  According to this (http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/slprtnr/rprtng/t2125/ln9060-eng.html) salaries and employer paid benefits are acceptable deductions.  I accept your assertion that payroll taxes will apply to the benefit, but why wouldn't this benefit be considered an expense?

Comment: @stackunderflow The specific benefit you've asked about, while it is a taxable-benefit, isn't employer-paid -- the employer *owns* the property. They aren't renting it. They may have maintenance costs, but those costs are mostly disconnected from the value they need to declare on the employee's T4 as a taxable benefit. AFAIK, a company can't claim a deduction for money they didn't spend. At the link you supplied, the kinds of employer-paid benefits that are listed are ones that actually require the employer to spend money. Hence, those costs, deductible.

Comment: I woudl imagine that the Canadian Tax authorities are treating this as a benefit in kind ie pay by another name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your view is correct when talking about unrelated persons.

However, in this case the renter and the landlord *are* related.

In most countries, and I'm sure so is Canada, any benefit above certain (very low) minimum that the employer provides to the employee is considered part of the payment for services provided by the employee (aka salary).

Thus, if the employee effectively receives a discount on housing, the tax principle says that such a discount is in fact an additional salary paid, and is taxed accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The discrepancy between the rent and the market value they are claiming is approximately 17%, so it's not like there's a blatantly obvious subsidy occurring here like, say, 50%.  It still seems to me that the employer could avoid doing this if they wanted to (as they have in the past) because the market value is a highly subjective number and the rent can be plausibly considered market value.  (They did this in the past, as mentioned, using "lack of amenities" as a prior justification).  Would you disagree with that assertion?

Comment: Sure the employer COULD avoid this, but why would they? They have a right to claim the difference between fair market rent and rent charged as a taxable benefit. So the dispute is really about the AMOUNT of the taxable benefit, Based on the information you have provided (how does $400 relate to 17%?), we cannot comment on this. If your friend can find a cheaper place (after considering taxes) to live elsewhere, then move.

Comment: @stackunderflow that would put them in jeopardy if the tax authority disagrees. Why would they? In fact, it is likely that the change came as a result of an audit, internal or external.

Comment: The employer is recording this taxable benefit to save money: this 'money' becomes taxable to the employee instead of to the employer.

Comment: @IT-RMT If an employer declares the benefit to the employee at $100, how would the employer then "save money" if they increased the declared value of the benefit to $200? I'm not following how that puts money in their pocket. The employee never paid any to the employer either way. Is there more than one step involved here?

Comment: To add to this the last part of the question - yes, the employer is required to take this deduction by law. If they failed to do it, they could be prosecuted. And also note that the employer is not making any kind of profit here (and you are still getting housing cheaper than you otherwise would).

Comment: So they used "lack of amenities" in the past and now they say "improved amenities"  If the amenities didn't actually change then it sounds like the result of an audit.  The CRA didn't like non-taxable benefit.  Of course the net result is a lower total compensation package.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea  The company should now be claiming a deduction for the taxable benefit paid.

Comment: @brian Got a source confirming that is possible? I'm skeptical about a company being able to claim a tax deduction for a non-cash benefit since they aren't directly incurring an expense. I could be wrong.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/pyrll/bnfts/menu-eng.html

Comment: The employer will declare the taxable benefit as a business expense, which will reduce the tax they need to pay.

In other words, they are shifting the tax burden of this amount from themselves to the employee.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea  I think you're right if the company DIDN'T add any amenities.  Their deductible expenses (maintenance, interest, depreciation, etc.) didn't change.  It must have been a CRA audit and they couldn't justify their FMV calculation.  IF that's the case the only cost (or lost benefit) to the company is possibly higher CPP and the need to pay more compensation.

Comment: @IT-RMT The reason why they might avoid doing this is because the goals behind this employee housing are to reduce commuting, provide units that are suitable for families (many apartments are not), and add some measure of cost certainty and affordability to the employee rents.  So what they are doing here undermines their supposed goals for the employee housing program.

Comment: @brian the employer's tax deduction doesn't change because of the change in the employee's benefit taxation. Employer didn't spend any more money, and didn't incur any more liabilities. This is not the same as the examples cited on the page you referred to. The employer in fact loses money, since the taxable benefit is added to the payroll taxes.

Comment: @littleadv - did you mean "taxable benefit INCREASES the payroll taxes?" e.g. employer has to pay 10% CPP+EI premiums on payroll amt,  so if payroll amt increases then so will the employer's share of CPP/EI premiums?

Comment: @IT-RMT of course

Comment: Thanks everyone for your insight here.  Can we safely say the consensus here is that the employer is indeed required to list this paid benefit and the only possible recourse here would be to attempt to dispute the fair market value used to calculate the benefit?